# Android Application Version (RAD Studio XE5)

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

How to get the version of an Android application using the Delphi XE5? I need the "versionName" information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getPackageInfo`method of the [`JPackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class to get information about you package, from here access the `versionName` property to get the `versionName`.

Try this sample

```
  uses
    Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
    FMX.Helpers.Android,
    Androidapi.Helpers,
    Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;


{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm25.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PackageManager: JPackageManager;
  PackageInfo : JPackageInfo;
begin
  PackageManager := SharedActivity.getPackageManager;
  PackageInfo := PackageManager.getPackageInfo(SharedActivityContext.getPackageName(), TJPackageManager.JavaClass.GET_ACTIVITIES);
  Edit1.Text:= JStringToString(PackageInfo.versionName);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, RRUZ. Perfect! Will be added to my library.