# How to get app versionname for android with delphi XE7?

Tags: android, delphi, version, delphi-xe7

I found one answer for delphi XE5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315571/android-application-version-rad-studio-xe5) but it doesn't work with XE7.

For instance is SharedActivity unknown.
Anyone who know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `uses` a little from the answer that you link to. I think that instead of:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
```

the code will work with:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers, 
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
```