# How can I get the version of my Android app on XE8?

Tags: delphi-xe8

How can I get the version of my Android app on XE8?

this code don't compile on XE8

```
  PackageManager := SharedActivity.getPackageManager;
  PackageInfo := PackageManager.getPackageInfo(SharedActivityContext.getPackageName(), TJPackageManager.JavaClass.GET_ACTIVITIES);
  result:= JStringToString(PackageInfo.versionName);
```

Comment: What is the actual compiler error?  On which line?

Comment: The compiler say

Undeclared identifier: 'JPackageManager'  

I have in the use,

Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
Androidapi.JNIBridge,
Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
FMX.Helpers.Android,
Androidapi.JNI.Net,
Androidapi.JNI.Os,
Androidapi.Helpers,
Androidapi.IOUtils,
Androidapi.JNI.App,
Androidapi.JNIBridge,
Androidapi.NativeActivity;

Comment: In XE8, `JPackageManager` is declared in the `Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText` unit. In any case, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315571/.

Answer (score 4):

Using the JPackageInfo class is simple to retrive the version of your Android application.

This class is already wrapped by Embarcadero in the following unit:
Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText

```
 {code}

 {$IFDEF ANDROID}

 var
   PackageManager: JPackageManager;
   PackageInfo: JPackageInfo;
 begin
   PackageManager := SharedActivityContext.getPackageManager;
   PackageInfo := PackageManager.getPackageInfo
     (SharedActivityContext.getPackageName, 0);
   result := JStringToString(PackageInfo.versionName);
 End;
{$ENDIF}
```