# C++ Builder: Get the version of Android application

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, firemonkey

I am developing an Android application with C++ Builder. I need to get the application version but I don't know how to do it. I already did it with a Windows application but with Android it's FMX and not VCL. Someone know how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315571/android-application-version-rad-studio-xe5

Comment: @KeremD I already tried that in C++: `JPackageManager* PackageManager = Androidapi::Helpers::SharedActivityContext()->getPackageManager();

 _di_JPackageInfo PackageInfo = PackageManager->getPackageInfo(SharedActivityContext()->getPackageName(), TJPackageManager::JavaClass->GET_ACTIVITIES);

 return Application->Title + " " + JStringToString(PackageInfo->versionName);` but I have a segmention fault at the 2nd instruction

Comment: `PackageManager` has to be of type `_di_JPackageManager` and not `JPackageManager*`

Comment: Thanks! It works now! Sorry for the duplicate question.